# Trying to send a json string C# .NET 7 - it works on Postman I keep getting bad request

Tags: c#, json

I need to send the following json string

```
{
    "Amount": 1,
    "TipAmount": null,
    "PaymentType": "Credit",
    "ReferenceId": "3892471",
    "PrintReceipt": "No",
    "GetReceipt": "No",
    "MerchantNumber": null,
    "InvoiceNumber": "",
    "CaptureSignature": false,
    "GetExtendedData": false,
    "CallbackInfo": { "Url": "" },
    "Tpn": "#######",
    "Authkey": "########",
    "SPInProxyTimeout": null
}
```

I have tried the following code I have separate classes for PostData and PostResponse.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace SendPostRequest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var postData = new PostData
            {
                Amount = 2.00,
                TipAmount = 0,
                PaymentType ="Credit",
                ReferenceId = "854980903",
                MerchantNumber =  0,
                Tpn = "######",
                Authkey = "#####",
                CallbackInfo = """Url""",
            };

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test.s###.net/spin/v2/Payment/Sale");

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(postData);
            var content = new StringContent(json,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
           
            var response = client.PostAsync("", content).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("contents"+json);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
            {
                var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
                };

                var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var postResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PostResponse>(responseContent,options);
                Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error" + response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `PostData` is not equal to your example above.

Comment: In C#, the `CallbackInfo` property is a string, but in the JSON, it's an object which contains a Url property.

Comment: Put a breakpoint down and inspect the value of `json` after its assignment. You'll be able to compare the JSON C# generate vs the JSON you manually send with your API testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

According to example, server expects an object in `CallbackInfo` property, not just a string:

```
var postData = new PostData
{
    Amount = 2.00,
    TipAmount = 0,
    PaymentType = "Credit",
    ReferenceId = "854980903",
    MerchantNumber =  0,
    Tpn = "######",
    Authkey = "#####",
    CallbackInfo = new { Url = string.Empty }
};
```

Comment: I have followed your suggestion for the call back info. Now I'm getting StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers: { Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 25 Oct 2023 13:15:00 GMT Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Content-Length: 36 }}

Comment: Well, something wrong on the server, it has problems with handling your request. The only way is to debug server, there is no way to guess on client side with just HTTP 500.

Comment: I noticed while testing in Post Man  it's sending the json string in the body . I think I'm sending as part of the header.

Comment: It's working now I had a couple of the fields defined incorrectly after I corrected them it gave me a positive result. Thanks for all your help and suggestions.